# .clangd: use different compiler flags depending on file extension

Tags: c++, c, configuration, compiler-flags, clangd

I am using the `.clangd` configuration file to pass compilation flags to clangd.

I run clangd on a codebase with C and C++ files.

How can I have some flags apply to C++ files but not C files ?

Comment: If your build system supports automatic generation of `compile_commands.json`, you should use it instead of manually configuring flags.

Comment: My build system is b2 which sadly not support `compile_commands.json` yet. I plan to try https://github.com/tee3/commands_to_compilation_database but I wanted to better understand `.clangd` possibilities first.

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple fragments and the `If` block syntax.

Example:

```
# Fragment common to C and C++ source files
CompileFlags:
    Add:
        - "--include-directory=some/directory/to/search/includes/in"
        - "-D"
        - "SOME_MACRO_TO_DEFINE"
        - "-include"
        - "some/file/to/force/inclusion/of.h"

---
# Fragment specific to C++ source files
If:
    PathExclude: [.*\.c, .*\.h]
CompileFlags:
    Add:
        - "-std=c++17"
```

`---` delimits fragments.

`PathMatch` could be more practical than `PathExclude` depending on the extensions in your codebase.

I tested this on clangd 13.0.0.

I got help from [this Github issue](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/431).

More help in [clangd official documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/config).